# svn how to apply changes in a revision range to an unrelated repo?

Tags: svn

So I have a file that was supposed to move to another repo. Instead it was just copied and development has continued in the original location.

I've found the changes I'm interested in:

```
svn diff -r14600:19400 ^/oldrepo/trunk/path/to/file.py
```

and those changes should be applied to `^/newrepo/trunk/new/path/to/file.py`

Is there a direct way to do this in svn -- or do I need to use something like `patch`? (I'm on windows, but have the gnuwin32 tools installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform any cross-repository operatons in SVN, thus - yes, you have to save patch from one repo and apply to another.

Good news - you *can* don't use any external tools: patch-file, saved with `svn diff`, can be applied to target with `svn patch` (maybe playing with some options will be needed only)